# there are no errors in my code but it's not running Automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I have a xlsm workbook that is always open wscopy and workbook always closed wsdest

I want it to copy all values from wscopy sheet to the closed workbook without it opening and to do that every 30 seconds automatically.

I fixed the code I have edited to be like below, I am not getting any error anymore, but still it doesn't work by itself every 30 seconds, it only works when i click Run sub when I am in the module.

any help please?

```
Sub clear_existing_data_before_paste()



Dim wscopy As Worksheet
Dim wsdest As Worksheet
Dim lcopyLastrow As Long
Dim ldestLastrow As Long


With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
     
End With

Set wscopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NEWROUND")
Set wsdest = Workbooks.Open("F:\DELEGATION APPLICATION\2-2023\DATABASE-2-2023.xlsm").Worksheets("All Data")

lcopyLastrow = wscopy.Cells(wscopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ldestLastrow = wsdest.Cells(wsdest.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

wsdest.Range("A2:N" & ldestLastrow).ClearContents

wscopy.Range("a2:n" & lcopyLastrow).Copy wsdest.Range("a2")

wsdest.Parent.Save

wsdest.Parent.Close True

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True

End With


End Sub


Sub timer()

Dim clear_existing_data_before_paste As String

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), clear_existing_data_before_paste


End Sub
```

Comment: You are clearing wsdest range based on `lcopyLastrow`.  Should be l`destLastrow`?

Comment: Thank u for that so much . Still have other problem though . I have ammended my question ‍♀️

Comment: Is the Sub inside a regular module? (Or did you put it into the ThisWorkbook module) - because You should probably have your subs and functions in regular modules (not in Workbook/Worksheet modules)

Comment: It is in the general Module. Module1 where all the subs are there not in thisworkbook module.

Comment: on your application ontime line `"clear_existing_data_before_paste)"` remove the parenthesis to `"clear_existing_data_before_paste"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application.OnTime` method requires two parameters - First the Time at which to run. And 2nd the procedure name to run. The procedure name has to be a string. So if I for example wanted to call the procedure with the name `test` after 10 sec. I would use

`Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"), "test"`

As it stands right now, You are passing an empty string (Because you declared a variable as a string and never assigned a value).

so either assign the string variable with the right value ("clear_existing_data_before_paste") or pass the value directly to your `Application.OnTime` function (like I did above with "test"

Answer (score 1):

do not use the sub name as a variable

```
Sub clear_existing_data_before_paste()

    Dim wscopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsdest As Worksheet
    Dim lcopyLastrow As Long
    Dim ldestLastrow As Long


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set wscopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NEWROUND")
    Set wsdest = Workbooks.Open("F:\DELEGATION APPLICATION\2-2023\DATABASE-2-2023.xlsm").Worksheets("All Data")

    lcopyLastrow = wscopy.Cells(wscopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ldestLastrow = wsdest.Cells(wsdest.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    wsdest.Range("A2:N" & ldestLastrow).ClearContents

    wscopy.Range("a2:n" & lcopyLastrow).Copy wsdest.Range("a2")

    wsdest.Parent.Save

    wsdest.Parent.Close True

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    'call timer sub again
    thirty_second_timer
    
End Sub


Sub thirty_second_timer()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "clear_existing_data_before_paste"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

the `application.ontime` function requires two parameters, when to run, and what to run. You need to add your sub to the code as the 'what to run parameter' eg.

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), clear_existing_data_before_paste
```

Comment: this is what I know but I tried that it gives me an error if u can check the screen shot. so I added "" it didnt work and i removed it completely also didnt work

Comment: actually it didnt... I dont know what to do any help?

Comment: any help please anyone?

Comment: The name of the procedure you want run, has to be passed as a String. The answer you provided will NOT work.